# Session Authentication when using file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Downloads in my project are protected by a PHP download script and session authentication.

On TCPDF generation i use **file_get_contents** and the script below to get the images and generate the pdf.

**stream_context_create** send the header PHPSESSID but there is still no authentication.

pdfexport.php:

```
    $opts = array( 'http'=>array( 'method'=>"GET",
                  'header'=>"Accept-language: de\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: ".session_name()."=".session_id()."\r\n" ) );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    session_write_close();  

foreach($data['we_files'] as $we_file){ 

    $getimage1 = file_get_contents( URLROOT . "/file.php?path=" .$we_file->image, false, $context);
    $image1_name = tempnam("/tmp", $we_file->image);
    file_put_contents($image1_name, $getimage1);
    $image1_image = new Imagick($image1_name);
    $image1_image->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    $image1_image->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
    $image1_image->thumbnailImage(500, 0);
    $image1 = '@'.base64_encode($image1_image);

echo $image1;
}
```

file.php

```
$path = $_GET["path"];
$search = 'uploads' ;
$pathnew = str_replace($search, '', $path) ;

header('X-Accel-Redirect: /uploads/' . $pathnew);
header('Content-Type:');
```

Imagick error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509
```

Debug:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://domain.de/file.php?path=uploads/481/8979fc24e116c4577a44424a8814c79b0d5c73d9-19-03-2019-08-28-11-SA-150.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in /var/www/clients/...

// DIE(print_r($opts));
Array
(
    [http] => Array
        (
            [method] => GET
            [header] => Accept-language: de
            Cookie: PHPSESSID=5krl856uibhugaf6p6n6hluufq

        )

)
1

//DIE(print_r($_COOKIE));
    Array(
     [PHPSESSID] => 5krl856uibhugaf6p6n6hluufq
    )
    1
```

Comment: Are you trying to access a local file through the network? Why not use the file system? If you really need to go through the http server, post the code that generates the 401 error

Comment: _“Downloads in my project are protected”_ - and that applies to what exactly? Is the image you are trying to read here considered a “download”, and therefor it’s protected by this mechanism as well? Any reason you are not simply reading the image contents via the file system, why the “round trip” via HTTP in the first place?

Comment: I try to access files from the same webserver. The authentication comes from file.php -> X-Accel-Redirect and nginx config: location /uploads { root /var/www/..../web/public; internal;}     The upload folder is located in public dir and files should be protected from public access and also have a role-session-based access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially trying to spoof the user session: perform an action pretending you're the user when you're actually a (potentially malicious) third party. If your sessions are set up securely, that won't work.

What you should do instead is verify the users' access permissions in code and read the image through the file system.

An alternative is creating a more complex system where services authenticate themselves against the back end, and pass in information that says "this user has authorized me to do this for them"

Comment: That´s correct. Maybe the session-management is also the explanation why the script worked in the past in older code ... So i will use the file system here. The protection script is still practicable for real user activities. Thank you.